# How can I set only some struct members to their default values?

Tags: struct, rust, default

I have struct `B`:

```rust
struct A {}

struct B {
    a: A,
    b: u32,
    c: i8,
    z: usize,
}
```

`A` does not have a `Default` implementation and no default that makes sense. The fields `b`..`z` all need to be initialised to the default (in this case, 0), and `A` will be initialised to some runtime value:

```rust
let b = B {
    a: some_a(),
    b: 0,
    c: 0,
    z: 0,
};
```

This is not ideal.

Even worse, if an `aa` were to be added to the struct, there would need to be another member added to the initialiser. Using `..Default::default()` doesn't work because `B` doesn't have a `Default` implementation, because any `A`s in the default will be too expensive to compute to simply throw away afterwards. Furthermore, I would need an extremely long struct initialiser in the `Default` implementation anyway.

Is there any way to set the remaining struct members to their default values (so that `b` would be set to the default of `u32`) without writing all the member names out?

Preferably, there should be minimum change required to struct initialisers when new members are added. This means this is not ideal:

```
let b = B {
    a: some_a(),
    b: Default::default(),
    c: Default::default(),
    z: Default::default(),
};
```

Comment: Is doing `b: Default::default(), c: Default::default(), ` and so on enough?

Comment: That is still 25 `Default::default()`s and I still have to add another one each time a new struct member is added.

Comment: That doesn't seem too bad to me personally.

Comment: Factor out all the non-A fields into their own struct and derive Default for that?

Comment: @me' rust doesn't (currently?) have any sort of "partial default", so your best bet is probably to provide a `new` which takes an `A` as input (or creates one) and sets everything else to their default values.

Comment: To be fair, if you are having that many fields in a single structure, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @mcarton That's not the actual struct and there aren't quite that many fields. It's because I want to get something done quickly for now, without changing 5 places every time add a field, and I don't want to write 1000 line functions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have large structs, you can make your life easier by deriving a builder or a constructor function. There are a few crates that do this, and a popular one is [`derive_builder`](https://crates.io/crates/derive_builder).

Using that crate, you can do something like:

```
use derive_builder::Builder;

// this derive will generate a struct called BBuilder
#[derive(Builder)]
struct B {
    a: A,
    #[builder(default = "0")]
    b: u32,
    #[builder(default = "0")]
    c: i8,
    /* ... */
    #[default(default = "0")]
    z: usize
}


fn main() {
    let a = A { ... };

    // all default values for fields b..z
    let b = BBuilder::default().a(a).build().unwrap();

    // or specify just some of the fields
    let b = BBuilder::default()
        .a(a)
        .c(42)
        .z(255)
        .build()
        .unwrap();
}
```

Adding new fields to `B` will not impact code that uses `BBuilder`, as long as the fields have defaults. The downside is that you get a runtime panic if you miss a required field, rather than a compilation error.

---

Another crate is [`derive-new`](https://crates.io/crates/derive-new), which is a bit simpler. You would use it like this:

```
use derive_new::new;

#[derive(new)]
struct B {
    a: A,
    #[new(default)] 
    b: u32,
    #[new(default)] 
    c: i8,
    /* ... */
    #[new(default)]
    z: usize
}

fn main() {
    let a = A { ... };

    // all default values for fields b..z
    let b = B::new(a);

    // To specify some of the default fields, you need to mutate
    let mut b = B::new(a);
    b.c = 42;
    b.z = 255;
}
```

This doesn't generate any extra structs, it just adds a `new` method, which takes all of the non-default arguments. It is a compilation error if you miss any non-default fields out.