# How to assign default value to struct members without explicitly calling `default` macro?

Tags: rust

I have a piece of code in which a struct is being used several dozen places:

```
pub struct MessageType {
    pub transaction: String,
    pub status: StatusType,
    pub reason: String,
}
```

Now, I would like to add another field `stream` to the structure:

```
pub struct MessageType {
    pub transaction: String,
    pub status: StatusType,
    pub reason: String,
    pub stream: String, // <-- this one to be added
}
```

Now I have to fix each usage of the struct through the codebase:

```
missing field `stream` in initializer of `MessageType`
missing `stream`
```

I have declared the `Default` trait like so:

```
impl Default for ]MessageType {
    fn default() -> MessageType {
        MessageType {
            transaction: "".to_string(),
            status: StatusType::ERROR,
            reason: "".to_string(),
            stream: "".to_string(),
        }
    }
}
```

But Rust still complains asking me to fix all instances of struct:

```
missing field `stream` in initializer of `MessageType`
missing `stream`
```

How do I go about without having to fix every instance of `MessageType` struct but also not having to accept unsafe usage or turn off any warning?

I also tried following based on suggestion from https://stackoverflow.com/a/61455568/11141793.

```
#[derive(Builder)]
pub struct MessageType {
    pub transaction: String,
    pub status: StatusType,
    pub reason: String,
    #[builder(default = "".to_string())] // <-- this one
    pub stream: String,
}
```

This introduces another error:

```
error: Unable to parse attribute: expected `,`
  --> message_type.rs:11:27
   |
11 |     #[builder(default = "".to_string())]
   |                           ^
```

I would like to achieve that `stream` is assigned a default value as in the `Default` trait, with no compiler errors.

I'm using `rustc 1.69.0 (84c898d65 2023-04-16)`.

Comment: Implementing `Default` does not enable any different syntax, it is just a normal trait with a normal function. You could use the [struct update syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html#creating-instances-from-other-instances-with-struct-update-syntax) (i.e. `..MessageType::default()`) to avoid specifying default fields, but you would still have to go and modify each usage with the additional syntax.

Comment: You aren't using the right syntax for derive-builder ([documentation](https://docs.rs/derive_builder/0.12.0/derive_builder/#default-values)), the default expression is a string, so it would have to be `"\"\".to_string()"`. Or you can just leave it as `#[builder(default)]` since `String` already has an empty string as its `Default` implementation.

Comment: But, there is no way to _not_ having the go through the entire source code and fix all instances of `MessageType`, correct?

Comment: @OoLoO Correct. You can prevent it for the next time, though, if you'll use `..MessageType::default()` now.

Comment: Thanks, all! I updated the code-base in the meanwhile.